# Current status of OpenID connect

Tags: openid

What is the current status of OpenID connect? I'd like to use this for a new SSO system. Are there any libraries available for implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Final OpenID Connect specifications were launched on February 26, 2014 as per http://openid.net/2014/02/26/the-openid-foundation-launches-the-openid-connect-standard/

Answer (score 1):

They're currently in "Feedback on Implementer's Draft" state. Next states are: "Final Review Period" → "Final Voting" → "OIDF Standard". See the OIDF's website [status page](http://openid.net/wg/connect/status/).

Answer (score 0):

A list of developer libraries for OpenID Connect in various languages/environments can be found here:
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/